# Google Apis Oauth1 to Oauth2 migration: Either the token is invalid or we could not decode it

Tags: php, curl, oauth, google-oauth

I wrote a PHP script to migrate from oauth1 to oauth2 using Curl, the headers are right and the form-data is also right but the response is always:

```
{
 ["error"]=>
   string(13) "invalid_token"
 ["error_description"]=>
   string(54) "Either the token is invalid or we could not decode it."
}
```

And here's the verbos of Curl:

> POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
>   Host: accounts.google.com
>   Accept: */*
>   Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="mykey.com", oauth_nonce="1416228848", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_token="1%252FNZL27URrdQlwLe", oauth_timestamp="1416228848", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="qcX5MW%2BuXUXsUyz7j7x8"
>   Content-Length: 230
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
 * upload completely sent off: 230 out of 230 bytes
 < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

And the postfields contains the oauth2 data:

```
 $params = [
  "grant_type"             => "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1",
  "client_id"              => $oauth2_client_id,
  "client_secret"          => $oauth2_client_secret,
  "scope"                  => "https://mail.google.com"
 ];
 $postData=http_build_query($params, '', '&');
```

I tried it on more than one token and it's returning the same message!

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? I now try to solve it too